# AJAX response size limitation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following jQuery to get the Pending Items and publish that in `#RightMenu` which is a `div`.

If the number of pending items is low, then the items will be published in the `div`, but if the number is high, then it does not publish them.

I have debugged the ASP.Net app to check if the data is returned in both cases, and no problem there.

Is there any limitation for the message returned to the jQuery?

```
function GetMyPendingItems() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "GlobalMethods.asmx/GetMyPendingItems",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
      $("#RightMenu").html(msg.d);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: If the message is very large, it may just take the browser a long time to render it.

Comment: You can check in your developer tools network tab if there's an error, and also in the console

Comment: How high is "high"?  Are you checking for errors in the console? With modern browsers rendering content is *very* fast.

Comment: The message returned is html menu holding the pending items, each item html is 800 bytes, if the return message is 200 items, then the menu not displayed!

Comment: Also, you only have a `.success()` handler. It would be useful to add a `.error()` handler and log what it says. 200 items times 800 bytes makes 160 Kb, this is nowhere near "big".

Comment: I have added the following : error: function (msg) {alert(msg.statusText);}, it alerts: Internal Server Error

Comment: "The message returned is html menu" ...then why are you returning the response as JSON?? That makes no sense. If you want to return HTML, then return raw HTML from the .NET code (and of course set `dataType: "html"` in the $.ajax() code). There is no sense in wrapping in a JSON object, it's just a pointless extra layer of processing and data.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution on the net, just add the following in the web.config

```
<system.web.extensions>
<scripting>
  <webServices>
    <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="5000000" />
  </webServices>
</scripting>
```